# Prevent an underscore "_" at the end of the content of a TextBox to be added

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I am working with nicks (given names).

When a user registers, you must enter your nick, the same, it cannot contain symbols (except the underscore), only numbers and letters.

I use the `KeyPress` event of my `TextBox` Username for this:

```
private bool Handled = false;

private void Username_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar)) this.Handled = false;
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\b') this.Handled = false; //Backspace key
        else
        {
           if (e.KeyChar == '_' && !((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains("_") && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length > 0) this.Handled = false;
            else this.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    e.Handled = Handled;
}
```

This piece of code prevents that symbols (different from " _ "), the content starts with " _ " and used more than one underscore "H_E_L_L_O" written, but they need to prevent that the underscore can be used at the end, I mean:

> Allow: Hell_o
>
> Prevent: Hello_

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

> I also used `String.Last()` but, the result is the same:

```
if(TextBox.Text.Last() == '_')
{
   // Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: You can write a regex which should end with a string char.

Comment: Wouldn't a comparison of the `SelectionStart` and `TextLength` in your `if` clause solve it?

Comment: `this.Handled = false` ?  Wouldn't that be `e.Handled`?

Comment: What does this mean: *"and used more than one script under "H_E_L_L_O" written"*?

Comment: @LarsTech Handled is a private bool

Comment: Of course you don't care if someone Paste text directly in the TextBox, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this unless you can read the user's mind :) After all, the user might want to put `Hell_o` like in your example but to type that they first need to type "Hell_" so you can't stop them at that point. The best you're probably going to do is handle the "Validating" event on the UserName control.

```
private void UserName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    errorProvider1.SetError(UserName, "");
    if (UserName.Text.EndsWith("_")) {
        errorProvider1.SetError(UserName, "Stuff is wrong");
    }            
}
```

Then in your "register" button click or whatever, check whether that control is (or any control you care about) is in error.

Comment: Would not it be better to use `String.Last()` instead of `String.EndsWith()`?